# Memory leak in multithreaded Optaplanner?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, quarkus, optaplanner

I seem to be getting a memory leak in Optaplanner. To reproduce, simply download the Quarkus example:

```
git clone https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts.git
cd quarkus-quickstarts/optaplanner-quickstart
```

Then change `src/main/resources/application.properties` by increasing the termination time (e.g. to `quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=10h`) and uncommenting the line that says `quarkus.optaplanner.solver.move-thread-count=2` to enable multithreading.

Then, run the request from the manual:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8080/timeTable/solve -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"timeslotList":[{"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","startTime":"08:30:00","endTime":"09:30:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","startTime":"09:30:00","endTime":"10:30:00"}],"roomList":[{"name":"Room A"},{"name":"Room B"}],"lessonList":[{"id":1,"subject":"Math","teacher":"A. Turing","studentGroup":"9th grade"},{"id":2,"subject":"Chemistry","teacher":"M. Curie","studentGroup":"9th grade"},{"id":3,"subject":"French","teacher":"M. Curie","studentGroup":"10th grade"},{"id":4,"subject":"History","teacher":"I. Jones","studentGroup":"10th grade"}]}'
```

Memory usage starts steadily increasing while millions of PhreakPropagationContext objects are made. I assume this is not expected behaviour. Should I create an issue for this or am I missing something?

Comment: It is only a leak if the memory is not used. What happens when the calculation has completed? Is memory reclaimed when the system is idle again? EDIT: https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner suggests limiting the search to 5 seconds, so when you let it run for 10 hours it will naturally consume more resources.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue. I kept the app running for 5 minutes and all I saw was a nice clean "chainsaw" pattern in memory use, with max heap used never exceeding 500 MiB.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Could you check for the number of PhreakPropagationContext objects? They're quite small so it's hard to see their effect on the memory use in just five minutes. For me the heap size only goes above 500 MB after about forty minutes, but it keeps rising steadily which is clearly visible after about fifteen minutes. See https://imgur.com/ASSVLaU . Note the manual GC trigger after about 4:20 PM which fails to clean up most of the memory. After about an hour I have 5 million PhreakPropagationContext objects. I don't really know what they are, but that seems like a high number.

Comment: @ewramner It does clean up the memory after the optimisation is done, but Optaplanner optimisations aren't usually supposed to have a steady increase in memory usage as far as I know.

Comment: So I let it run for longer (~15 minutes), and there does appear to be a very slow increase of heap use that is not being reclaimed. There is really no reason why that should be happening. The culprit does indeed seem to be the PhreakPropagationContext, which would point to a leak in Drools.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Should I make an issue in the Drools issue tracker then?

Comment: Please file a PLANNER JIRA, we'll have to investigate it a bit more before we show it to the Drools folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed your question, investigated the issue and ended up [filing a bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2550). The fix is scheduled to be included in OptaPlanner 8.13.0.Final.